# MonoTouch.Dialog Image only cell

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'am working on a app where the user can put in some data and then take a image with the camera or from the device.

The problem i'am having is that i cant seem to get a cell or element to only display a image.
Width of the image would be the width of the cell(Grouped style) it's in. Height i would like to specify myself.

I've tried to subclass ImageElement but can't change the size of it.

Is the already a Element i could use for this or is there any other good way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the UIViewElement with an UIImageView:

```
var imageView = new UIImageView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 300, 100));
imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
var element = new UIViewElement(String.Empty, imageView, true);
```

Comment: This is defenetly a step in the right direction. Image shows up and i can set the size of it. Now one problem remains, the cell does not change height.

Comment: You will need to inherit UIViewElement and override the GetHeight method.